# Comparing multiple groups of lists (Python)

Tags: python, list

I have 6 lists grouped by 3 in 2 groups. In each group they are linked beetween them, and are equal in legth, but the two groups are not equal in length. First list of each group is considered a control list. Now I need to compare the two groups of lists by their 2 control lists and to output a unified intercalated result.

These lists in fact are columns of two assimetric tables with common entries in the header-columns. So I try to align and sort the tables by these common entries, creating a new table by appending these two on common entries.
Here is a graphic represenation of the desired procedure:
[image]

How could I do this in Python?

Comment: Looks like a job for either a SQL database or pandas.

Comment: What kind of data structure do you have these in now in Python?  Or are we at ground zero?

Comment: I think this is called outer join. Here's [the relevant Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go for pandas:

1. Read each with `df1 = pandas.read_excel(path_to_file)`
2. Use `df3 = df1.join(df2, on='List1', how='left')`
3. You can export to excel back again if you wish with `df3.to_excel(path_to_file)`

Comment: What if the groups of lists are irregular? The 1st group has elements not present in the 2nd group, and the 2nd group has elements not present in the 1st group.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for the shorter lists, rest is straight copy so I guess no problem there

```
import numpy as np

l1 = np.arange(9)
l2 = np.ndarray(6)
l2[0:3] = np.arange(3)
l2[3:6] = np.arange(6, 9)

#Here starts solution
res = np.ndarray(max(len(l1), len(l2)))
res[:] = [None for i in range(len(res))]

if len(l1) > len(l2):
  longer = l1
  shorter = l2
else:
  longer = l2
  shorter = l1

idxs = 0
while True:
  #Index of first unchecked value from shorter in longer
  idxl = np.argwhere(longer == shorter[idxs])[0][0]
  #Length of equal data
  l = sum(np.equal(shorter[idxs:], longer[idxl:idxl+len(shorter) - idxs]))
  #Copy equal data with indexing of longer array
  res[idxl:idxl+l] = shorter[idxs:idxs+l]
  #Move forward in search
  idxs += l
  #Whole shorter array searched
  if idxs == len(shorter):
    break

#Output of res: array([ 0.,  1.,  2., nan, nan, nan,  6.,  7.,  8.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing to pandas. Very useful library for such a task.
I did it so:

```
left = pd.DataFrame(
    {'index': list1,
     'l2': list2,
     'l3': list3,
     'l4': list4
    })   
right = pd.DataFrame(
    {'index': list5,
     'l6': list6,
     'l7': list7
    })
result = pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', on='index')
```

where all the lists are defined prior to this.